# How does scala map("key") = "value" translate to map.update("key", "value")?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I understand that `map("key")` is possible because `Map` implements `Function1`. But how does `map("key") = "value"` translate to `map.update("key", "value")`? I don't see a `=` function defined anywhere in `Map` or its parent interfaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This translation is simply implemented as a rule in the Scala compiler. See the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#assignments):

> An assignment f(args) = e with a function application to the left of
>   the ‘=’ operator is interpreted as f.update(args, e), i.e. the
>   invocation of an update function defined by f.